Find the measure of the angle formed by OB and the perpendicular bisector of AC in the triangle below.
If you have a triangle $ABC$, where $m∡⁢⁢=20^$.In the extension of $BC$, mark $"N"$ such that: $CN = AB$. The perpendicular bisectors of $AC$ and $BN$ intersect at $"O"$.
Calculate the measure of the angle formed by OB and the perpendicular bisector of AC.
If $m∡⁢⁢=30^$.
(Answer:$5^o$ )
I try:
$\angle ABC = 180^o - 30^o -20^o = 130^o $
$\angle MQC = 180^o -90^o -20^o = 70^o $
$BP=PN$
$AM = CM$
$\angle POQ = 180^0 - 90^o -70^o = 20^o$
How do I finish?



Draw $OA$ and $OC$
$OA = OC$ ($OM$ is $\perp$ bisector, $\triangle AOC$ is an isosceles)
$OB = ON$ ($OP$ is $\perp$ bisector, $\triangle BON$ is an isosceles)
$AB = CN$ (given)
$\triangle AOB \cong \triangle CON$ (S.S.S Congruent Theorem)
then
$\angle CAO = \angle ACO = \alpha$
and
$\angle BAO = \angle OCN = \alpha + 30^{\circ}$ (Congruent $\triangle's$)
$20^{\circ} + \alpha + \alpha + 30^{\circ} = 180^{\circ}$ (straight $\angle$)
$\alpha = 65^{\circ}$
then
$\angle AOB = \angle CON $ (Congruent $\triangle's$)
$\angle POC = 5^{\circ}$ (in $\triangle POC$)
and
$\angle BOQ = \angle POC = 5^{\circ} $

Excellent, thanks for help
